# Is it possible to call a method when any action is called in a whole controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to call a specific method when any actions are called to do some work.  I was wondering if this was possible?  I do have a basecontroller for all the controllers but currently there is nothing in there.

i.e. 
If I go to the index page a call is made to the controller to the index action method when that method is called I want to do some work then continue with the action.  I am trying to avoid calling this method all over the place in every single action and see if there is a universal way of calling it every where.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is something exactly for this. You're looking for [filters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513%28v=vs.98%29.aspx), more specifically the [`OnActionExecuting`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.onactionexecuting%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) one.

> If this method is overridden in a derived Controller class, it will be called for every action method in the class. For more flexibility, derive a class from ActionFilterAttribute and override this method in the derived ActionFilterAttribute class.

Sample:

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext ctx) {
    base.OnActionExecuting(ctx);
    ctx.HttpContext.Trace.Write("Log: OnActionExecuting",
         "Calling " +
         ctx.ActionDescriptor.ActionName);
}
```

Comment: is it possible to set something to the viewbag in there?

Comment: Yes. It is just a normal method that will be invoked before any action method in your controller is called.

Comment: Note that you have 4 places to override, post pre action execution, and post pre ActionResult execution.

If you want to manipulate pre conditions to the action do it in the OnActionExecuting, and similarly for the post action execution.

The other two overloads are where you can manipulate the response.

There is no need to call base, it will always be empty.